# Page freezes while ajax working

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I use ajax with jquery, page freezes while ajax working and then after 3-4 seconds, data received. I set time interval on the ajax function to run again and again after few seconds and that make my page very slow.

How can I prevent this?

Code that I use is given below.

```
    function show_clt() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: true
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "online_clients.php",
            //data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#online_clients").html(html);
            } 
        });
        var dataString = "e_id=<?=$employer_id; ?>";            
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "online_employer.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#online_employer").html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    show_clt();
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: true
        });
        //var di_scroll = $('#client_main').scrollTop(); alert(di_scroll);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "online_clients.php",
            //data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#online_clients").html(html);
                //$('#client_main').scrollTop(60);
            } 
        });
        var dataString = "e_id=<?=$employer_id; ?>";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "online_employer.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#online_employer").html(html);
            }
        });
    }, 9000);
```

Comment: Don't call ajax request together. If may, you can use jQuery.queue() to make your request in an queue (https://gist.github.com/gnarf/1039247).

Comment: Could you please format the code. Tabs are confusing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will be executing ajax functions all the time no matter whether or not they have finished, if these queries take a long time to complete you could possibly end up with a lot of queries running simultaneously.

The below code will chain the queries so that they will only run once the previous has completed.

```
    function show_clt() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: true
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "online_clients.php",
            //data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#online_clients").html(html);
            }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            var dataString = "e_id=<?=$employer_id; ?>";            
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "online_employer.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#online_employer").html(html);
                }
            }).done(function(msg) {
                setTimeout(function(){ show_clt() }, 9000);
            });
        });
    }

    show_clt();
```

Using the `.done()` function of the [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) object we can execute the next command. Once the next command has completed we call the `.done()` function on this and set a timeout of 9 seconds to re-call this entire function.

The only issue with this is that the data will not be refreshed every 9 seconds exactly, but it will be refreshed every : 9 seconds + 1st ajax response time + 2nd ajax response time. Depending on the speed of your ajax queries the amount of time shouldn't be noticeable and will end up being something around 10-11 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably not related to AJAX call itself. If you try and remove all the `$("#online_clients").html(html);` etc. code from your success functions, I think the actual problem will go away.

That said, it's the actual HTML repositioning and updates that make the browser "freeze" until it can re-populate and re-display the page. Since you're doing 3-4 such calls at the same time, this behavior is to be expected.

My suggestion would be to only update what you really need and when you really need it. Possibly chain those AJAX calls, so they don't fire up together, make artificial pauses between them or just really update *some* of the elements on page as the need so.

Comment: how can i chain these?

Comment: perhaps by using the [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (check the [promise function](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)) in jQuery or by calling the next AJAX in the previous one's `success` function